# Why does every shape only have a single connector suddenly?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I've just started a new diagram in Draw.io and realised every shape only has a single, central connector point:

[image]

I was just working on another diagram and the same object types have connectors around the edges/corners. It means even the most basic diagram task is impossible as arrow tails/heads are hidden.

Is this some setting in the template I chose? How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change something under Extras > Configuration?
If not, click Clear default Style at the right. Does it help?

If not, check if you see this in other browsers and Incognito mode and if needed, copy/paste diagram data here. Data can be found under Extras > Edit diagram